# I can no longer read and write on my firestore emulator

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a problem with my firebase emulator. More precisely with the firestore service of the emulator. It does not work anymore. The other services are working fine.

I can no longer read and write in my firestore emulator. I noticed details but I don't know where to see a more relevant error message.

on my UI I noticed this message which was not there before
[image]

in my firestore log file `firestore-debug.log` I have this message.
[image]

my project id is `mycaredev-27ea8` not `dev~mycaredev-27ea8`

this is the only information I can find. My application sends me a message telling me that it can't find the data I'm looking for or it just doesn't save the data I want.

please can someone help me?

thanks